# Creating a Popup in .Net Maui but "InitializeComponent()" ist not being recognized

Tags: c#, initialization, maui

I want to create a Popup with two Buttons. I have actually created other Popups just like this before but this time it doesn't work because the `InitializeComponent()` method `does not exist in the current context`.

C#-Code:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;
using SiRiAs.Lib.Helpers;

namespace SiRiAs.Views.Popups;

public partial class DeletePopup : Popup {
    public DeletePopup() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Delete_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) => Close(DeletePopupResult.Delete);
    private void Keep_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) => Close(DeletePopupResult.Keep);
}
```

Xaml:

```
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="SiRiAs.Views.Popups.DeletePopup">
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Padding="15" Spacing="20">
            <Button Style="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}"
                    Text="Ja,löschen"
                    Clicked="Delete_Clicked"
                   />
            <Button Style="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}"
                    Text="Nein, nicht löschen"
                    Clicked="Keep_Clicked"
                    />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</toolkit:Popup>
```

I don't see, that I am doing anything different then written in the Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup

Also If I look up `InitializeComponent()` in the other Popups, it brings me to a file, that I cannot added, that is auto-generated.

The auto-generated file of another Popup, the `MoreOptionsPopup`, just as a reference with what I mean by auto-generated file

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a .NET MAUI source generator.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[assembly: global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlResourceId("SiRiAs.Views.Popups.MoreOptionsPopup.xaml", "Views/Popups/MoreOptionsPopup.xaml", typeof(global::SiRiAs.Views.Popups.MoreOptionsPopup))]
namespace SiRiAs.Views.Popups
{
    [global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlFilePath("Views\\Popups\\MoreOptionsPopup.xaml")]
    public partial class MoreOptionsPopup : global::CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views.Popup
    {
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("Microsoft.Maui.Controls.SourceGen", "1.0.0.0")]
#if NET5_0_OR_GREATER
#endif
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(MoreOptionsPopup));
        }
    }
}
```

I tried building the project and closing VisualStudio, switching branches. I must oversee something but I don't know what and where.

I appriciate the help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Maui syntax yet but shouldn't the code be in the  `SiRiAs.Views.Popups` namespace block

Comment: I am 99.99% sure, that your DeletePopup.xaml has build actions set to NONE, instead of MauiXaml. Right click on it, and see if that is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I tested your code. Now I am 100% sure everything is ok.
(I trust you have .UseMauiCommunityToolkit() in your MauiProgram.cs)

Most people forget to set Build Actions of their XAML file. You can:

1. Right click on XAML > Properties > Build Action MauiXaml.
2. Remove the file from the project and re-add it. (It will default to that build action)

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code to my app and did a test on my android emulator, but it works well on my side.

You can try to delete the bin folders and the obj folders and rebuild it. If it doesn’t work,try to restart the Visual Studio.

Or you can create a new demo and copy your code to this new demo and try again.